# Firebase auth : Build functions must never return null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a small problem, I have an error that started to occur when I changed a piece of code, I only added the try, catch.

The account created with the old code, still works, but not the new one, I have this error after registration (there is a redirection to the member page), and at login, only on the new user account.

Error (The first two lines are the prints):

```
flutter: {nom: Toto, prenom: Tata, estAbonne: false, books: [], uid: xyDSRJ6o7ebgjnjzuoeK47ZrDId2}
flutter: User(displayName: null, email: toto@tatagdjg.fr, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2021-08-22 00:54:47.946, lastSignInTime: 2021-08-22 00:54:47.946), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: toto@tatagdjg.fr, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: toto@tatagdjg.fr)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: xyDSRJ6o7ebgjnjzuoeK47ZrDId2)

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MainController(dirty, state: _MainControllerState#c1d7a):
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: MainController
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
```

firebase_handler.dart (I think the error is here):

```
Future<User> createUser(String mail, String pwd, String nom, String prenom,
      BuildContext context) async {
    prenom = Gadgets().capitalize(prenom);
    nom = Gadgets().capitalize(nom);

    try {
      final userCredential = await authInstance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: mail, password: pwd);
      final User user = userCredential.user;

      Map<String, dynamic> memberMap = {
        nomKey: nom,
        prenomKey: prenom,
        estAbonneKey: false,
        booksKey: [],
        uidKey: user.uid
      };
      //Add User
      await user.sendEmailVerification();
      addUserToFirebase(memberMap);
      print(memberMap);
      print(user);
      return user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
        _show(context, "Mot de passe faible");
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
        _show(context, "Email deja existant");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

main_controller.dart:

```
class MainController extends StatefulWidget {
  String memberUid;
  User user;

  MainController({@required this.memberUid, this.user});

  @override
  _MainControllerState createState() => _MainControllerState(user: user);
}

class _MainControllerState extends State<MainController> {
  // ignore: cancel_subscriptions
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;
  Member member;
  User user;

  _MainControllerState({this.user});

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamSubscription = FirebaseHandler()
        .fireUser
        .doc(widget.memberUid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        member = Member(event);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (member == null) {
      return Loading();
    } else {
      if (user.emailVerified) {
        return HomePage(member: member);
      } else {
        VerifiedMailPage();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The error indicates that your `build` function has a code path that does not return a non-`null` value.  The `VerifiedMailPage();` line should be `return VerifiedMailPage();`.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @jamesdlin :)